# Generate model entity class from MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, jdbc

I'm using Spring framework with Netbean, and I try to auto generate model entity class from my MongoDB database. so Is it possible to do that ? because I'm not sure I missing the concept to do that or not for MongoDB dose not have really structure ?

Actually I used to generate model with MySQL Connecter/Driver from MySQL DB and it's work.

Can someone advise me ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Mongodb does not have a predefined structure. So, in a collection(equivalence of table in mongodb) you can save different types of data and mongodb accept them all. For example consider these data:

```
{
  "someKey": 5
}

{
  "someKey": "5"
}

{
  "someKey": 
    {
      "someField": "some field",
      "someOtherField": ISODate("2017-08-17T08:37:37.581Z")
    }
}
```

All above of 3 json data can be insert in same collection. So a framework or a plugin cannot determine a structure from a collection's already inserted data too.